# flutter HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter, dart-http

It happens only for  image Urls
Loading the Following image  causes the issue

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = https://wagstays-static-cdn-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_89/pet/wagstays_pet_.2d7f49042718400aa970361186dc7e0e.jpg
```

```
 Image.network(snapshot.data.imageUrl,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.98,
               ),
```

Comment: show Widget code which calls this url

Comment: added the widget code

Comment: I appears to be part of future builder. Please post complete future builder widget code, may be you missing handling of states and errors